# Subsampling years before and after an event of an unbalanced panel dataset

Tags: stata

I'm trying to figure out a concise way to keep only the two years before and after the year in which an event takes place using daily panel data in Stata. The panel is unbalanced. Ultimately, I'm trying to conduct an event study but I experienced issues because the unique groups report inconsistent years.

The data looks something like this:

```
ID   year   month    day    event
1    1999     1       1       0
1    1999     1       2       0
1    1999     1       3       0
1    1999     1       4       0
1    1999     1       5       0
1    1999     1       6       0
1    1999     1       7       0
1    1999     1       8       0
1    1999     1       9       0
1    1999     1       10      0
1    1999     1       11      0
1    1999     1       12      0
1    1999     1       13      0
1    1999     1       14      0
1    1999     1       15      0
1    1999     1       16      0
1    1999     1       17      0
1    1999     1       18      0
1    1999     1       19      0
1    1999     1       20      0
1    1999     1       21      0
1    1999     1       22      0
1    1999     1       23      0
1    1999     1       24      0
1    1999     1       25      0
1    1999     1       26      0
1    1999     1       27      0
1    1999     1       28      0
1    1999     1       29      0
1    1999     1       30      0
1    1999     1       31      0
1    1999     2       1       1
1    1999     2       2       1
```

In this case, the event takes place in February 1999. The event is monthly, but I need the daily data for a later part of the analysis. I want to somehow tag the 24 months before February 1999 and the 24 months after February 1999. However, I need to do this in a way that won't codify any months in 2002 if group 1 reported no data in 2000.

I got the following to work on a similar set of monthly data but I can't figure out a way to do it with daily data. Furthermore, if anyone has suggestions for a less clunky solution, I would be very appreciative.

```
bys ID year (month) : egen year_change = max(event) 
bys ID (year month) : replace year_change = 2 if /// 
    (year_change[_n+24] == 1 & year[_n] == year[_n+24] - 2) | /// 
    (year_change[_n+12] == 1 & year[_n] == year[_n+12] - 1) | ///
    (year_change[_n-12] == 1 & year[_n] == year[_n-12] + 1) |  ///
    (year_change[_n-24] == 1 & year[_n] == year[_n-24] + 2)
keep if year_change >= 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your event date is the first date with `event` 1. So,

```
gen dailydate = mdy(month, day, year) 
bysort id : egen key = min(cond(event == 1, dailydate, .)) 
gen wanted = inrange(dailydate, key - 730, key + 730)
```

Check that `wanted` gives the dates you want and then modify the rule or `keep` accordingly.

This code doesn't assume that the event date is the same for each panel, but that would not be a problem.

See [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055) for a review of related technique.

Answer (score 0):

For your task, I suggest you to work use actual Stata dates, instead of relying on year + month + day variables - this way, it would be easier to add/subtract 24 months without relying on data sorting (the "_n+24" part in your code) and the codification would not suffer from the issue with missing data that you outline in the question.

I see a straightforward solution, which relies on an assumption I made on your setting (that you did not specify, but is the general form of event studies): the event date is unique for all IDs, hence there is no group-specific "treatment" date.

```
g stata_date = mdy(month, day, year) // generate variable with Stata date
/* Unique event on Feb 1, 1999 */
bys ID: egen treat_group = max(event) // indicator for an ID to ever be "treated"
g event_window = (stata_date >= td(01Feb1997) & stata_date < td(01Feb2001)) // indicator for event window - 2 years before and after Feb 1, 1999
g event_treatment = treat_group * event_window // indicator for a treated ID during the event window
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that in my case there are group-specific treatment dates. The other answer works in my case though. Thank you for your input